# adding class to .img not producing animation out

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

This animates my `img` sliding `in` however I'd like to get it to animate `out`. I've tried adding a class on `click` but it doesn't seem to work. Any insight appreciated.

IMG:

`<img id="slide" src="img/40-Slide.png">`

CSS SLIDE-IN (works):

```
#slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -785px;
    width: 246px;
    height: 685px;
     -webkit-animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
     animation: slide 0.5s forwards;    
}


@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    100% { left: 0; }
}

@keyframes slide {
    100% { left: 0; }
}
```

CSS SLIDE-OUT (not working):

```
.slideOut {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 246px;
    height: 685px;
     -webkit-animation: slideOut 0.5s forwards;
     animation: slideOut 0.5s forwards; 

}

@-webkit-keyframes slideOut {
    100% { left: -175px; }
}

@keyframes slideOut {
    100% { left: -175px; }
}
```

JQUERY:

```
    $("#page8").click(function(){
        $('#slide').addClass('slideOut');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS Specificity

Change

```
.slideOut {
```

to

```
#slide.slideOut {
```

---

```js
    $("body").click(function(){
        $('#slide').addClass('slideOut');
        });
```

```css
#slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -785px;
    width: 246px;
    height: 685px;
     -webkit-animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
     animation: slide 0.5s forwards;    
}


@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    100% { left: 0; }
}

@keyframes slide {
    100% { left: 0; }
}




#slide.slideOut {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 246px;
    height: 685px;
     -webkit-animation: slideOut 0.5s forwards;
     animation: slideOut 0.5s forwards; 

}

@-webkit-keyframes slideOut {
    100% { left: -175px; }
}

@keyframes slideOut {
    100% { left: -175px; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="slide" src="img/40-Slide.png">
```

Comment: it seems to work with the `body` click but not with my `li` `#page8` click — any reason?

Comment: I do not know what your markup is...SO....I can not tell you why it would not be working.

Comment: Sorry!

`$(window).load(function(){ 
 $("#page8").click(function(){
 $('#slide').addClass('slideOut');
  });   
});`

Comment: That is the JS code in your post, What element is #page8 exactly?

Comment: So if the JS is generating the ids, are you add the onclick before the element is added to the page? `$(document).on("click", "#page8", function(){ $('#slide').addClass('slideOut'); });`

Comment: I think the issue may be because my lis are generated on the index and im trying to add the class to the img in the iframe?